# Epson Perfection V500 scanner not working with Image Capture on macOS 11.5 (Big Sur)

Tags: image-capture

After installing Epson ICA Driver version 5.8.9, I can't get the scanner to work in macOS 11.5 (Big Sur).

After launching Image Capture, I get the error message:

> You do not have permission to open the application "EPSON Scanner"
> Contact your computer or network administrator for assistance

How can I get my scanner to work? - it looks like I have the latest version from Epson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this is something to do with Gatekeeper, which is designed to ensure that only trusted software runs on your Mac.

I was able to resolve the problem by running the following command in the Terminal:

```sh
xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine /Library/Image\ Capture/Devices/EPSON\ Scanner.app
```

After that the scanner works fine!